# Write() failing EBADF despite many successful writes

Tags: c, linux, file-io

Hope you guys can point out my obvious mistake;

System is embedded linux, code in c.

We have some code in a cgi script which accepts a data stream from the (Boa) webserver (a file upload) on STDIN_FILENO and writes it out to a temporary file ("/tmp/file.txt").

Code below is a much simplified snippet, but basically shows the order of things:

1. Open temporary file fd to write to
2. Get N bytes from STDIN
3. Write N bytes to temp file
4. lather, rinse, repeat until no more bytes (or error)

The expected file is a binary, about 20Mb, but the writes always fail at about 1.4Mb with errno 9 (EBADF) which suggests the file descriptor got closed somehow.

There is plenty of disc space and the web server is not limiting the POST filesize or truncating the data.

**Code:**

```
char buffer[1024];
mode_t fd_mode=S_IRWXU;
if ((targ_fd = open("/tmp/file.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, fd_mode)) == -1)
{
    OUTPUT("Error opening file\n");
    return FAIL;
}

while(total < maxlen)
{
    count = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, 1024);
    if(count > 0)
    {
       if(write(targ_fd, buffer, count) < 0)
        {
            perror("Failed to write to file");
            close(targ_fd);
            return FAIL;
        }
       total += count;
    }
    else
    {
        return FAIL;
        // Or success if EOF, code omitted for clarity
    }
}
```

With smaller files (but big enough to require multiple writes) it works perfectly.

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

*Edited to add:* Updated code, and:

We do catch read() returning 0 but I omitted it for clarity.
Program is single-threaded, after initially trimming the MIME headers from the first read() data it simply reads into buffer & then writes buffer to temp file until it hits maxlen or end of input.

Additional note: The writes do succeed initially, a file is created with the correct content, up to the size where it fails.

**Update with further tests:**
Following helpful comments / suggestions:

- count is an int, no problem with signedness there.
- I had forgotten to check the return value of write(), the last write() before failure does not manage to write the full number of bytes requested. Changing open() to add the flag O_SYNC does not make any difference.
- I added fstat() and debug prints both on open() and on failure:

Code:

```
printf("File type:                ");
switch (filestat.st_mode & S_IFMT) {
case S_IFBLK:  printf("block device\n");            break;
case S_IFCHR:  printf("character device\n");        break;
case S_IFDIR:  printf("directory\n");               break;
case S_IFIFO:  printf("FIFO/pipe\n");               break;
case S_IFLNK:  printf("symlink\n");                 break;
case S_IFREG:  printf("regular file\n");            break;
case S_IFSOCK: printf("socket\n");                  break;
default:       printf("unknown?\n");                break;
}

printf("I-node number:            %ld\n", (long) filestat.st_ino);
printf("Mode:                     %lo (octal)\n",
    (unsigned long) filestat.st_mode);
printf("Link count:               %ld\n", (long) filestat.st_nlink);
printf("Ownership:                UID=%ld   GID=%ld\n",
    (long) filestat.st_uid, (long) filestat.st_gid);
printf("Preferred I/O block size: %ld bytes\n",
    (long) filestat.st_blksize);
printf("File size:                %lld bytes\n",
    (long long) filestat.st_size);
printf("Blocks allocated:         %lld\n",
    (long long) filestat.st_blocks);
printf("Last status change:       %s", ctime(&filestat.st_ctime));
printf("Last file access:         %s", ctime(&filestat.st_atime));
printf("Last file modification:   %s", ctime(&filestat.st_mtime));
```

Results are, on **open**:

```
Fd = 5
File type:                regular file
I-node number:            486
Mode:                     100600 (octal)
Link count:               1
Ownership:                UID=0   GID=0
Preferred I/O block size: 4096 bytes
File size:                0 bytes
Blocks allocated:         0
Last status change:       Thu Jan  1 00:00:51 1970
Last file access:         Thu Jan  1 00:00:51 1970
Last file modification:   Thu Jan  1 00:00:51 1970
```

Results on error:

```
Fd = 5
Failed to write to the pipe (errno = 9), managed 273 / 4096 bytes
File type:                regular file
I-node number:            486
Mode:                     100600 (octal)
Link count:               1
Ownership:                UID=0   GID=0
Preferred I/O block size: 4096 bytes
File size:                1499136 bytes
Blocks allocated:         2944
Last status change:       Thu Jan  1 00:00:51 1970
Last file access:         Thu Jan  1 00:00:51 1970
Last file modification:   Thu Jan  1 00:00:51 1970
```

Yes, the system clock isn't set.

**More info:**
After failure:

```
root@IPNC:~# df -i /tmp
Filesystem Inodes Used Available Use% Mounted on
none 5664 7 5657 0% /tmp
root@IPNC:~# df /tmp
Filesystem 1K-blocks Used Available Use% Mounted on
none 25600 1508 24092 6% /tmp
```

**Further info as requested:**

The MIME trimming that goes on simply skips over the first data that arrives until the "\r\n\r\n" before the data, so the first write starts reading from part-way through the buffer. I have checked that this is starting at the correct point & ending at the correct point, and with smaller test files (~50k) the entirety of the file is correctly received & written with no errors, over-runs or under-runs.

**Results of further testing:**

Well, it's still not fixed. The point of failure moves with different input data (both file size & type), but doesn't seem to trip over any particular pattern or data (E.G: One file fails in the middle of a large chunk of 0xFF's).

I have tried using fcntl() to lock the fd, using dup() and working on the new fd in case the other one was somehow being closed externally, neither makes any difference.

I'm going to try inserting dummy data and seeing if I can successfully write *filesize* bytes of dummy data.

** Finally near the end...**

It looks as if Boa handles HTTP POST requests in an odd way, writing them to a temporary file, dup'ing it to the STDIN of the target CGI script. This would be fine if there was enough space in /tmp for two copies, but there isn't (we're embedded). A few oddities remain: the file it creates never shows up in file listings, and the write failure does not indicate "out of space". Some odd stuff is going on for sure, but for now I think this is not exactly a failure of write(), but some bigger issue in the parent code.

Comment: There's not enough code to determine what goes wrong. What is the size of `buffer` in the read() call ? What is `tp` used in the write call, and what else does the code inbetween reading and writing ? (i.e. is there a buffer overflow somewhere ?) Also - is this program single threaded ? You'd also do good to check the read() call for errors.

Comment: You should really check the returned value from `read` as well.

Comment: You're not checking for `EOF` on `stdin`.

Comment: And what if read() returns 0.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated question to clarify: buffer is char buffer[1024], we __do__ catch read() returning 0 but I omitted it for clarity. tp is a pointer to buffer which is not relevant, it only moves in the 1st read when we trim the MIME headers and is then set to point to the start of buffer every time, I've removed it in the example as tp === buffer when the code fails. @Barmar - I've assumed read() returning 0 is == EOF, or is there some other check I should be making?

Comment: Program is single-threaded, after initially trimming the MIME headers from the first read() data it simply reads into buffer & then writes buffer to temp file.

Comment: What's your libc & platform, in case it matters?

Comment: Well if you ged a EBADFD on write, you *could* inspect the value of `targ_fd` after the error (it most probably has been overwritten by code that you did not show)

Comment: @joop - Good suggestion, I just tried that and the fd didn't change.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis - It's GCC and the target is Ti Davinci DM36x SoC (an Arm9 core).

Comment: I suspect you have a buffer overflow, so when you think you're modifying `buffer`, you're messing up `targ_fd`. We'll need to see the real code, not this sanitized version, to be sure.

Comment: `read()` can return -1 on error (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html) so if `count` is defined as an unsigned type you might run into some issue related to that.

Comment: Use `df` and `df -i` on `/tmp` after failure. Use also [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on your whole program.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - I added df results to question.

Comment: Can you show us the mime-trimming bit?

Comment: @JohnHascall - Added info to question. We just read the 1st chunk of input, scan with strstr() to find the MIME boundary and adjust the start pointer & length of the 1st write. It works perfectly with other/smaller files.

Comment: 1) 2 thoughts:  Uncomfortable with a text file (".txt") for binary data and not explicitly opening the file in binary mode. 2) Try doing just the read.  3) Try doing just the write file with dummy data.

Comment: If the problem is related to limited FS space on /tmp 1) do you have enough memory to keep the contents in memory ? 2) *unix-trick* : unlink the file after opening. The file descriptor will stay readable/writable, but it will no longer refer to blocks on the disk.

Comment: @chux - .txt is kinda irrelevant, Kernighan & Ritchie: __"...our fopen does not recognize the "b" that signals binary access, since that is meaningless on UNIX systems..."__ K&R,2nd ed'n,p.178

Comment: Bizarrely, read() works, we can malloc() the full amount of RAM to read into, but due to the tightness of resources in the system a load of other stuff then fails as "out of memory" (there's a shitstorm of high-bandwidth video streaming going on alongside this). I think we just need to work out some other way (splitting the file, using tftp, etc.) of getting the data up there. I don't really want to re-write half of Boa just to get around a hardware limitation. Guess the next hardware needs more rams!

Comment: @John U the `'b'`` option is well specified in the C specs of 1999 and 2011.  Certainly Linux systems adhere to those specs and will recognize it as a legitimate option - even if is a no-op.  The K&R,2nd from 1988, is informative concerning UNIX history.  In any case, when a problem is especially challenging to solve, often some premise is incorrect.   The binary/".txt" presented are fringe thoughts - use as you see fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I guess I should close this...

The answer, such as it is, is a bit complex.

Originally I said "we have plenty of disk space", which we do, until Boa decides to buffer the entire POST data (~20Mb) in the /tmp folder (total free space ~25Mb), which then makes writing the file data to /tmp quite tricky, and explains why write() failed later the smaller the file was (around 25Mb minus filesize), presumably if the file was 12.5Mb it would just about succeed.

Anyway, the goose chase was made wilder by the odd return code (EBADF) rather than any sort of out-of-space indication.

The disappointing upshot of this is we'll have to work out some other scheme of uploading the file to the device directly, either by some other means (tftp, wget) or use a script in the upload page to split the file into chunks and upload a chunk at a time.

Comment: Out of space in general is handled "funny" on Linux. Just like `malloc()` will not return `NULL` because it will not attempt the page swap until you first *access* the memory...